# Buffered Reader Returns Null

Tags: java, ajax, json, bufferedreader

Hi i send an ajax call to server like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "...",
    dataType:'json',
    data:JSON.stringify(contact),
    success:function(){
        alert("success")
    }
```

At server i handle this request and trying to read the json object from request like this.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

but br.readLine() returns null. Any idea why it happens?

Comment: this will give you null because through `AJAX` it won't possible try as submitting by POST Button. It'll work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it and there is no problem with how you use the HTTP request InputStream. The 'contact' element is most likely undefined at the time of the request. Therefore it is converted to an empty JSON string.
Try adding some fixed text to the 'data' field and you should see it working on server side.

Answer (score 1):

Because you reached the end of the stream.

From the JavaDocs:

> **Returns:** A String containing the contents of the line, not including any
>   line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been
>   reached

Very likely an empty result is returned, the problem is somewhere else then. I don't know if the AJAX request is send as a body of the request, or as a POST parameter. Use request.getParameter("json") instead might help, but check with LiveHttpHeaders first, how your browser encodes the request and which parameter name is bound to the data. In this case you don't have to work with readline at all.

Comment: but it dont enter while loop because br.readLine() always returns null

Comment: Yes, because your stream is always empty! Verify by checking that request.getInputStream().read() returns -1!

Comment: You could for instance try to examine network traffic with wireshark.

Comment: it was working great two days ago then i changed my session manager from http session manager to memcached session manager then this error occured i dont know how to fix :S

Comment: -1 on question. Thanks for wasting our time by withholding this information.